# DataStage integration with Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, etl, datastage

I Need help in how we can integrate GITLAB with ETL (Data stage) tool. Currently the developers are exporting the file from data stage and pushing it manually to the Gitlab repositories. Need automate this process.

I tried checking out metalci but seems it doesn't have direct integration with Gitlab.